# Why using locks to read/write shared memory is faster than not using locks

Tags: python, python-3.x, locking, python-multiprocessing, semaphore

I am experimenting Python multiprocessing and I am surprised to see counter intuitive results while using locks.

My assumption was that while using shared memory, if we use a lock to ensure only one process can access the shared object at a time, all the other processes will wait for the locking process to release the lock before reading/writing on the shared object. So although this ensures data integrity and eliminates race conditions, this will also inevitably cause all but one process to wait on a locking process. As a result the overall time of execution will be longer than while not using locks. If no locks are used, none of the processes will wait on each other and so will finish faster but will also corrupt the data.

With this understanding in mind, I wrote a quick program to find out exactly how much slower is it to use a lock, but surprisingly it seems using a lock is actually significantly faster.

Can you explain why is it faster to use a lock? Is something wrong with my understanding of how locks work? Or is there something wrong with the way I’ve setup the experiment (code below).

If `lock.acquire()` and `lock.release()` are **commented** out, so NOT using lock, it takes **75.85** seconds,
If `lock.acquire()` and `lock.release()` are **Uncommented**, so using lock, it takes **57.17** seconds
I am using Python 3.7,
Running on Intel i7 8550U, 4 physical cores, (8 threads with hyperthreading)

```
import os
import multiprocessing as mp
from timeit import default_timer as timer


def func(n, val, lock, add):
    for i in range(n):
        lock.acquire()  # uncomment to use lock
        if add:
            val.value += 1
        else:
            val.value -= 1
        lock.release()  # uncomment to use lock
        if i % (n/10) == 0:
            print(f"Process: {os.getpid()}, {(i / n * 100):.2f}%")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    start = timer()
    lock = mp.Lock()
    n = 2000000
    val = mp.Value('i', 100)
    arr = mp.Array('i', 10)

    p1 = mp.Process(target=func, args=(n, val, lock, True))
    p2 = mp.Process(target=func, args=(n, val, lock, False))

    p1.start()
    p2.start()

    p1.join()
    p2.join()

    elapsed = timer() - start
    print("Time elapsed = {}".format(elapsed))
    print(f"Val = {val.value}")
```

Comment: Cannot confirm your findings. On quite dated hardware (2012), I get ~14.8 sec with locking and ~4.1 sec without. Are you running this on a single-physical-core-cpu?

Comment: @Darkonaut, I am using a Intel i7 8550U, 4 physical cores, 8 threads with hyperthreading

Comment: How do you run it (terminal or which IDE) and on which OS? Does your system already occupy all cores before you start the script?

Comment: @Darkonaut I run it on PyCharm IDE, OS is Windows 10, I make sure my system consumes ~0% CPU before starting the test

Comment: Try running it from terminal. If you are on Python 3.7.2 update to a later version. So far you didn't mention anything suspicious what would indicate a reason for your strange timings, though.

Comment: @Darkonaut, I just ran on a terminal, got exactly same results, not using lock: 77.2745139 sec and using lock: 57.6813798 sec